# jQuery Mousewheel Plugin Multiplying Delta Factor

Tags: jquery, scroll, mousewheel, multiplication

i am using the jQuery Mousewheel Plugin and ran into a problem i can't figure out alone.

I wrote a function where i check for two screen sizes via window width.
The first checks if the window width is bigger than 768px, if so, i want the site to scroll horizontally. The second one checks if the window width if below or equal 768px, if so, i want the site to scroll vertically.

The function gets called inside the document ready function and inside the window resize function. It works well, until i start resizing my browser manually. If i do so without refreshing the page, the mousewheel speed seems to multiply everytime i resize the window.

Here is a bit of code to show you guys:

```
function resize() {

    if ( $(window).width() > 768 ) {

        // Scroll horizontally
        $('#scroll').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
            this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
            event.preventDefault();
        });

    }
    else if ( $(window).width() <= 768 ) {

        // Scroll vertically
        $('#scroll').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
            this.scrollTop -= (delta * 40);
            event.preventDefault();
        });

    }

}

$(document).ready(function() {

    resize();

});

$(window).resize(function() {

    resize();

 });
```

Any idea how i could fix this? Or is there a better way to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `$('#scroll').mousewheel(function () { ... })`, you are adding a new handler for the `mousewheel` event. The "multiplying" effect you are seeing is the result of several event handlers adding to / subtracting from `scrollLeft`/`scrolltop` at the same time.

You will want to remove any previous `mousewheel` handler in `resize()`, either with [`.off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) or `.unmousewheel()`, before adding a new handler.